# Python Histogram using matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, histogram

I've written a python script that parses a trace file and retrieves a list of objects (vehicle objects) containing the vehicle id, timestep and the number of other vehicles in radio range of a particular vehicle for that timestep:

```
for d_obj in global_list_of_nbrs:
    print "\t", d_obj.id, "\t", d_obj.time, "\t", d_obj.num_nbrs
```

The sample output from the test file I am using is:

```
0   0   1
0   1   2
0   2   0
1   0   1
1   1   2
2   0   0
2   1   2
```

This can be interpreted as vehicle with id 0 at timestep 0 has 1 neighbouring vehicle, vehicle with id 0 at timestep 1 has 2 neighbouring vehicles (i.e. in radio range) etc.

I would like to plot a histogram using matplotlib to represent this data but am confused what I should do with bins etc and how I should represent the list (currently a list of objects).

Can anyone please advise on this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want a histogram or just any appropiate visualization of the data?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Do you want to look at a histogram of neighbor counts, across ID? As far as data representation goes, I would recommend using pandas, as it excels at this kind of data analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of something you might be able to do with this data set:

**Note:** You'll need to install [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) for this example to work for you.

```
n = 10000
id_col = randint(3, size=n)
lam = 10
num_nbrs = poisson(lam, size=n)

d = DataFrame({'id': id_col, 'num_nbrs': num_nbrs})

fig, axs = subplots(2, 3, figsize=(12, 4))

def plotter(ax, grp, grp_name, method, **kwargs):
    getattr(ax, method)(grp.num_nbrs.values, **kwargs)
    ax.set_title('ID: %i' % grp_name)

gb = d.groupby('id')

for row, method in zip((0, 1), ('plot', 'hist')):
    for ax, (grp_name, grp) in zip(axs[row].flat, gb):
        plotter(ax, grp, grp_name, method)
```

[image]

What I've done is created 2 plots for each of 3 IDs. The top row shows the number of neighbors as a function of time for each ID. The bottom row shows the distribution of the number of neighbors across time.

You'll probably want to play around with [sharing axes](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html?highlight=sharex), [axes labelling](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xlabel#matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel) and [all the other fun things](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) that [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) offers.